# Material SearchView implementation error

Tags: android, material-design

I'm developing an android app, by now everything great, but when try to implement a Material SearchView with Google guidelines and following step by step some tutorials I can't figureout this error:

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_ad"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Buscar"
        android:visible="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/publish_ad"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Publicar anuncio"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favs"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Configuración"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_ad).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

error:

```
06-16 15:36:51.021 1239-1239/com.bachecubano.elbache E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.bachecubano.elbache, PID: 1239
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
       at com.bachecubano.elbache.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2889)
       at android.support.v4.b.m.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.h$b.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.q.j(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.q$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Comment: Ehi, I hope that you solved your issue. If yes, please accept one answer. It will help future devs ;) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have added the following code on your manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityWhereYouWantYourSearch">
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

And this on your *res/xml* folder (named *searchable.xml*) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search_description" />
```

I will also put a check on your `onCreateOptionsMenu`, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_ad);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
    }
    return true;
}
```

BTW, I don't use `android:enabled` and `android:visible`, but it's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this kind of SearchView but from the error I would guess that it can't get the ComponentName of the Activity. What I would try now is to put a this before getComponentName() --> this.getComponentName() to make sure where it should get the ComponentName.

Just a guess, so please don't hate me if that's wrong ^^

Comment: Hm... There are some nullable things in the code of the onCreateOptionsMenu() but the code looks ok and I don't think that there is something wrong with this code. The only thing I have in mind now is that you maybe don't have anything searchable in you Activity. What do you want to search?

Comment: The strange issue is: when I use it in debug method from Android-Studio Shift+F9 everything goes great, the problem came when I Generate a signed APK.

Comment: Well that's strange. But I've done some research and I want to take one last guess on your first submitted error:

So since the SearchManager getSearchAbleInfo() returns null I assume that something in your configuration is wrong and your Activity isn't searchable.

I would take two steps back and insure that you've created your searchable configuration right. For this take another look at the Google tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableConfiguration
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity

Answer (score 2):

You have to return true from `onCreateOptionsMenu` in order the inflation to take place. Therefore you get a `NPE` when trying to access `menu` before the return statement.

So remove those four lines of code to the appropriate method [onPrepareOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

Comment: nothing, same error, I searching for a good library on GitHub to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue with your code is that you are using the latest version of support library but using the old style to access the "SearchView", that's why it's returning null. Use this line of code to access your searchview through "MenuItemCompat":

```
 SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

Check this blog for more details:

https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
return true;
```

add this line

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```