# searchview issue in a specific device androidx

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I have moved my code to androidx it is working fine in other devices but I'm getting

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference at packagename.FileName.onCreateOptionsMenu (FileName.java:43)`in **VIVO Devices**

following is my menu code

```
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/w_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
```

I am not able to figure out for what reasons this is happening.

EDIT:

for context if it helps, I was having similar issue in `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` but after adding              `app:passwordToggleDrawable="@null"` it was resolved

EDIT 2:

SearchView code

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.w_hint_search));

    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#5FFFFFFF"));
    searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Please show code for SearchView Class

Comment: app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" Your issue might be because of the androidx. Try using appcompact

Comment: @HuzaifaAsif Are you sure, it's right way to migrate to the AndroidX? :D

Comment: @GensaGames He's using AndroidX app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" so i was refering that he should try reverting back to appcompact. May be that would help him. I'm not asking or telling him to migrate to android x and neither it is a way of migrating to android x :)

Comment: try `android:actionViewClass` instead of  `app:actionViewClass` it may help

Comment: Don't revert to AppCompact. Is your import correct? import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView; I also use app:actionViewClass so I doubt that is it

Comment: Have a look at this link : [searchview-implementation-error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787758/7138532)

Comment: verify the package of SearchView is androidX library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as based on the few suggestions in the comment and I wasn't able to find any concrete answer I did following to resolve the problem 
first I changed menu from `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` to `android.widget.SearchView`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/w_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

and changed my `java` imports from `import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;`
 to `import android.widget.SearchView;`

Technically it doesn't answer the problem but resolved my issue so I'm posting it as an answer.